# Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" and "end of file" issue that has my procedure not working?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, declare

For homework im suppose to print out payment_total and invoice_total for a procedure with a parameter is vendor_id. It compiled but it said the declared was wrong im not sure if my syntax is wrong or what the issue is.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE vn_payment(vendorID in number)
IS
DECLARE
payment_total vendors.vendor_id%type;
invoice_total vendors.vendor_id%type;
BEGIN
Select vendor_id from vendors 
where vendor_id = vendorID;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('payment total:' || payment_total || 'and invoice total'
|| invoice_total);
END;
```

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BlG8.png)

Comment: remove the "DECLARE"

Comment: Declaring variables `payment_total` and `invoice_total` to have the data type of column `vendor_id` doesn't make sense, aside from your syntax issue (`declare` is used for anonymous blocks, not for procedures - it **replaces** the `create or replace procedure ... is` fragment). Then: Shouldn't you select the payment total and the invoice total from the table, not the vendor id? The vendor id is needed for the `where` clause, but it shouldn't be in the `select` clause.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `DECLARE` keyword in a procedure and you also need to `SELECT ... INTO ...`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE vn_payment(vendorID in number)
IS
  payment_total vendors.vendor_id%type;
  invoice_total vendors.vendor_id%type;
BEGIN
  Select vendor_id, vendor_id
  INTO   payment_total, invoice_total
  from   vendors 
  where  vendor_id = vendorID;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
    'payment total:' || payment_total || 'and invoice total'|| invoice_total
  );
END;
/
```

*However, you probably want to select the totals and not the id.*